# Bootstrap-wysiwyg редактирование контента

Tags: wysiwyg, bootstrap

Добавил в форму `bootstrap-wysiwyg`, всё хорошо. Контент красиво редактируется, сохраняется в БД.

При попытке изменения -- в форме отображаются html-теги, а не визуализируется вёрстка.

Как сделать, чтобы при редактировании сохранённый в БД записи -- например, **жирный текст** -- отображался красиво, а не с тегами &lt;b>жирный текст&lt;/b>?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Текст вставляете, например, между <div> и </div>

Затем:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#editor').cleanHtml();
});
```